# What does "snaking out" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I saw this phrase in [this article](http://www.vogue.com/13517958/istanbul-turkey-before-terrorist-attacks-isis/) today. Specifically, here is the sentence;

> In the early hours of the military coup in July, I joined a line of Turks snaking out of my local deli and stuffed water bottles and beer cans in my pockets, preparing for the long night ahead.

Couldn't make out what it meant the first time I read it. I can infer that it means 'turning its' insides out' or just 'eating through something' from the context but I'm looking for a more in-depth meaning I guess and where else (typically) do you use this phrase?

Comment: The movement of the line of departing Turks is compared to that of an emerging snake. Their motion reminds the writer of the sinuous movement of a snake.

Answer (score 3):

> a snaking line

looks and moves like a snake

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not such a snaky line.  This one is more snaky:  http://s.wsj.net/public/resources/images/BN-AT513_1212ma_J_20131212102118.jpg

Comment: Oh brother, I didn't even think of this, wow... makes sense now, thanks...